# How to add One Click Payment Cards in payUbiz?

Tags: android, paypal, payumoney

I have integrated `payubiz android sdk` and using [this](https://developer.payubiz.in/documentation/Android-SDK-Integration/71) link for integration.

for one touch payment i used to

```
// To store one click payment hash pass 1
mPaymentParams.setEnableOneClickPayment(1);
```

and

```
mPaymentParams.setCardCvvMerchant(merchantHash);
```

but both are method not find with mPaymentParams object ?

So please provide me how it will work?